# rust and JNI crate - converting java objects to byte array and back returns them with nulled fields

Tags: java, rust, java-native-interface

So I try to implement a stupid way to serialize some more complex objects by simply getting their binary representation and storing it. In rust I made the following 2 functions using JNI crate:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "system" fn Java_Test_Test_toBytes(env: JNIEnv,
                                            class: JClass,
                                            input: JObject)
                                            -> jbyteArray {
    println!("slicing and dicing!");
    let size = size_of_val(&input);
    println!("size of input: {}",size);
    let mut buff: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(size);
    unsafe {
        copy(<*const _>::cast(*input), buff.as_mut_ptr(), size);
        buff.set_len(size)
    };
    println!("collecting stuff from chopper, its`a {:?}", buff);
    env.byte_array_from_slice(buff.as_slice()).unwrap()
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "system" fn Java_Test_Test_castBytes(env: JNIEnv,
                                  class: JClass,
                                  buff: jbyteArray,
                                  mold: JClass)
                                  -> jobject {
    println!("rejuvenating");
    let size = size_of_val(&buff);
    println!("size of buff: {}",size);
    let mut m_buff: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(size);
    unsafe {
        copy(<*const _>::cast(buff), m_buff.as_mut_ptr(), size);
        m_buff.set_len(size)
    };
    println!("got values {:?}",m_buff);
    let mut out = env.alloc_object(mold).unwrap();
    unsafe {
        out.write_bytes(*m_buff.as_mut_ptr(), size);
    }
    out.into_inner()

}
```

In java I've made a test object

```java
public class UwU {
    private String uwu;
    private String owo;

    public UwU() {
        uwu = "uwu";
        owo = "owo";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UwU : {" +
                "\n uwu: " +
                this.uwu +
                "\n owo: " +
                this.owo +
                "\n}";
    }
}
```

this is my main function where I test the functionality

```java
public class Main {




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File fl = new File("ffi/ser.dll");
        if (fl.exists()) {
            System.load(fl.getAbsolutePath());
            UwU uwu = new UwU();
            System.out.println("im "+uwu);
            System.out.println("uwu be sliced...");
            byte[] owo_bits = Test.toBytes(uwu);
            System.out.println("uwu slurry : "+Arrays.toString(owo_bits));

            System.out.println("restoring uwu");
            uwu = (UwU) Test.castBytes(owo_bits, UwU.class);
            System.out.println("im "+uwu);

        } else {
            System.out.println("No lib!");
        }
    }
}
```

However the output I'm getting is

```
im UwU : {
 uwu: uwu
 owo: owo
}
uwu be sliced...
slicing and dicing!
size of input: 8
collecting stuff from chopper, its`a [248, 113, 182, 216, 0, 0, 0, 0]
uwu slurry : [-8, 113, -74, -40, 0, 0, 0, 0]
restoring uwu
rejuvenating
size of buff: 8
got values [216, 150, 182, 216, 0, 0, 0, 0]
im UwU : {
 uwu: null
 owo: null
}
```

I'm not sure if that has to do with the way java stores child objects, as I suspect it might not include them into object reference and store them somewhere else - just because it seems to be weird to allocate so much memory on stack and then strings would be like rust Vec, so they would be just the pointers to heap data.

In any case I'm looking for a way to serialize all of the object - any hints anyone can give me?

Comment: In java, all variables/fields are actually pointers to heap allocated objects. Thus every time you write the "byte-by-byte" representation you are storing some pointers to only god knows where. Even if it worked in your example, it will not work in the general case

Comment: Why not actually use Java serialization (`Serializable`)  (in your case with JNI)?

Comment: @SvetlinZarev thanks - so i guess the question is solved, can u answer it so i can mark it?

Comment: @g00se because I wanted to store very complex objects which I don't want to subclass. particularly I thought of a system for my Minecraft mod to add entities as tags.

Comment: OK. You probably could do that with your own VM of course as that would give you total control